# How to refresh tokens for gmail api programmatically?

Tags: gmail, google-oauth, cypress, access-token

I'm writing Cypress tests that need to run in CI and some of those tests require checking gmail. I followed the gmail api [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) and used the provided program to generate a token that's saved to disk. The token is saved with this format:

```
{
   access_token:
   refresh_token:
   scope:
   token_type:
   expiry_date:

 }
```

The token contains a refresh token so I can reuse the same file for my tests and it works. But after about 7/8 days the tests fail, saying the token's been revoked.

I want to make another request for a new token, but the program provided in the quickstart needs to be done manually (provides a link that a person visits, signs in with their gmail, get a code they paste back in the terminal). Is there any way to request a new token programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your refresh token has expired then the only way to get a new one is to request access of the user whos data you are trying to access by displaying the consent screen to them.

I think the main issue is why your refresh token is expiring for the most part refresh tokens shouldnt expire however ..

Refresh tokens for apps which are in production and have been through googles verification process do not expire

refresh tokens which were created by applications which are still in testing only last at max two weeks.

If the user changes their password this can also expire a refresh token which was created using gmail scopes

Comment: Okay that must explain it. The app is still in testing because it's only being used for internal e2e tests so I never bothered verifying it. Is the only way to have a non-expiring refresh token to have a verified app?

Comment: This is not something I have tested personally but I have been contacted by a lot of people lately who are having the same issues as you.   I suspect this is a stealth change.  I have been unable to get any information out of my google contacts on this though